# beautifulsoup attrs matching too much

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, matching

Html is something like this:

```
<div class="score header">text i don't want</div><div class="score">text i want</div>
```

I do beautifulsoup like this, bs.find("div", attrs={"class":"score"}) and it is matching the first div tag.  I am surprised bs is acting like this.  Obviously I could do bs.findAll(...)[1] but i think that is too ugly a solution.  How do I match this more properly.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is a HTML parser and as such it'll look for a class attribute *containing* the specified class. Just like CSS rules would.

Answer (score 0):

Class matching in BeautifulSoup matches *per* class in the class attribute.

To filter out elements that match *more* than the stated class, you can use a generator expression:

```
next((el for el in bs.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"score"}) if el['class'] == ['score']), None)
```

This returns the *first* element that matches the class *exactly* with no other classes allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First `<div>` has both `score` and `header` classes. If you want elements without `score`, you should filter them afterwards

```
items = soup.find_all(...)
good_items = [item for item in items if 'score' not in item['class']]
```

Of course, filtering condition depends what you want to match exactly

```
'score' not in item['class']
```

or

```
['score'] == item['class']
```

Have in mind that `item['class']` returns `list` of classes that the item has. So if you want to match more than one class, then you should use [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
set(['foo', 'bar']) == set(item['class'])
```